# Getting unwanted junk characters in mail body

Tags: asp.net

I am generating mail description(body) in ASP.Net and insert into Table. but when i am sending mail to recipient generating some junk characters in the mail body like `!`.

junk characters are not getting when i copy the description and checking the mail description in html file.

Expected word is `technicians`
result is `techni! cians`

can any one help me why its coming. how to create proper email in HTML ?

Comment: I think the error is on the line 42

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: i have resolved the issue by adding propert style='word-wrap: break-word' for <p>